# Video unable to play on Safari and IE9, but plays perfectly on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, video, html5-video

I'm pretty new to all of this HTML business, but I managed to learn enough to get it online for the time being: (www.authenticchronicles.com).

Right now, it's only two pages, and it's the "about" page is what's giving me some issues. After spending about 3-4 hours trying to tackle this, I just about ready to give up! Maybe someone here can provide some insight? FWIW, I'm using dreamweaver to put it all together.

I swear my html is correct:

```
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted volume="0">
<source src="movies/about.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
<source src="movies/About.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="movies/About.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

and it works... to a point. Only chrome and firefox will actually load the background looping video (I'm using CSS to place it in the background). Safari and IE9 fail to load, and it's just a blank box.

I even tried to edit the htaccess file by adding this to what was previously blank:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
```

I tried updating my browsers, and everything. I have the correct doctype listed at the top of the html:

I have no idea what's going on. What's interesting is that, while I'm editing on dreamweaver, I can PREVIEW on these sites locally just fine (naturally, I figured it would work when I uploaded it to the host). It's when it's uploaded to the host and then accessed that's giving me issues.

I apologize if this seems redundant and an easy fix. I swear I've done as much research as I can, and tried to understand as much as possible. I'm just completely stumped at this point. Any insight into this issue is much appreciated~

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain about the solution, but here's something to test: Try adding the attribute 'controls' to the video tag, e.g.:

```
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" controls autoplay loop muted volume="0">
```

Where I'm going with this is that the 'autoplay' video tag attribute is not always honored by all browsers (it could be annoying, intrusive, and bandwidth-intensive). By asking for controls, you will be able to mouse over the blank video area and press a play button. This will verify whether IE9 and Safari are at least able to play the video.